# Taking Input from user and storing it in an array

Tags: c, arrays, input

I'm really new to C so it would be great if someone could tell me how I can do this:
I am trying to get user input using fgets. So if the user enters the following integers:
1 2 3 4 5

How do i scan them and put them in an array of ints= [1,2,3,4,5]

Here is what I am trying to do right now: I am continuously looping and asking the user to input a number until the user does not put anything. In each iteration, I am saving the input of the user to the array

```
int myArray[200];
char input_str[1024];

fprintf(stdout, "Enter numbers: ");

if (fgets(input_str, sizeof(input_str), stdin) == 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error returned from fgets()...\n");
    exit(1);
}

sscanf(input_str, "%d", &n);
myArray[i]=n;

//The while loop will continue as long as the string is not null
while( input_str[0]!='\0'){

    if (fgets(input_str, sizeof(input_str), stdin) == 0){
        break;
    }
    for (i=1;i<201;i++){
        sscanf(input_str, "%d", &n);
        myArray[i]=n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to have the `fgets` outside the loop? The `for` should have `i<200`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int myArray[200];
    char input_str[1024];
    int i, n = 0;
    size_t full = sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(*myArray);

    fprintf(stdout, "Enter numbers: ");

    while(fgets(input_str, sizeof(input_str), stdin) != NULL){
        char *p = input_str;
        int v, len;

        if(*input_str == '\n' || n == full)
            break;//input end if blank line

        while(1==sscanf(p, "%d%n", &v, &len)){
            myArray[n++] = v;
            p += len;
            if(n == full)
                break;
        }
    }
    //check print
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ", myArray[i]);
    return 0;
}
```